# Get a free seat (randomizing?)

Tags: php

i have a global variables which handles if users standing on "items" (on seats) or just standing on the seat. Therefore i have 2 global variables as mentored.

```
 $users[$someUserID]['seat']     <----
```

and this:

```
  $standing[$someSeatID]['seat'] <----
```

which handles if user is standing on a seat.

Now i will make a function that gives me a random seat which is free and not taken by other users. How can i make this?

```
$random = mt_rand(0, 97);
```

But how can i check if it's also free in

```
 $users[id..]['seat']
```

and

```
 $standing[seat..]['seat']?
```

Comment: What is the reason you are using global variables to store this information?

Answer (score 1):

You could try building an array of unused seat IDs and then retrieve a random array index from this array.

Note that if the datatype of the seat is fairly large (and not, for example, an integer) and you have thousands of these, this could cause performance issues and you might need to simplify the seat representation to avoid this.